# How to recognize an ARMA process?

Tags: arima, stochastic-processes, discrete-time

By looking at the autocovariance, how could you recognise what discrete model (MA(q), AR(p), or ARMA(p,q)) is more appropriate to describe your data?

Comment: Have you tried the power spectral density?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Do you mean comparing spectral density of the prediction errors?

Comment: Take the autocorrelation of your signal. Take the autocorrelation of the MA / AR / ARMA processes. Compare. If you don't like it, take the Fourier transforms and make the comparisons in the frequency domain.

Answer (score 2):

A $MA(q)$ process has zero autocorrelation for lag bigger than $q$. Instead, the autocorrelation of $AR$ and $ARMA$ processes extends to infinite, with exponential tails. And that's basically all you can say, I think.

Comment: As you mention, these are properties of the models. My question is related to the real data and how to determine which is the most appropriate model (p and q) that describes it. Maybe cross-correlation or domain specific knowledge can shed some light.